# Best way to self destruct all data on a linux server?

Tags: linux

We have recently upgraded a number of our servers. We are now left with a few servers we are ready to hand back to our data center.

Anyone know what is the best way to do a final self destruction of all the data on these servers before handing them back?

We obviously dont want to physically harm the servers, just purge, as permanently as possible all of our data on these boxes.

Comment: Belong on superuser but you can find utilities to zero write all the hard drives

Comment: Three votes to close as off-topic. Why? Isn't this part of a sysadmin's job? I've personally have to sanitise many hard drives as part of my duties.

Comment: This seems like an appropriate question here (I run into this question several times a year in my job), and I don't see any good reasons why it was closed. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I endorse all the other recommendations for DBAN, but if you really can't do this, I've had a lot of success with shutting down as many services as I can (esp. the windowing system), then doing

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=1000k
```

from a root shell prompt, sitting back, and waiting.  This basically writes pseudorandom bytes, a megabyte at a time, all over `/dev/sda` (you may need to use `/dev/hda` or other device as appropriate to your setup).

Because the kernel and the tool are in-core, the system will stay up for a surprising amount of time while this is running, and it leaves an utterly unbootable and mostly-completely-scrambled system behind it.

Comment: DBAN is the obvious choice when circumstances permit. Unfortunately not in our case. That is why I chose this as the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you're interested in a bootable solution, I would suggest checking out [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/)

Comment: nice tool! did not know about this. we wont be able to use this as getting them to burn this, boot it for us, etc, will be a headache. but will definatly keep this in mind for the future! thanx.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have (remote) access to server console before booting? You can add [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) to grub.conf and run it from grub menu (use `kernel=dban.bzi` with `dban.bzi` copied from downloaded ISO file).

Wiping disk from under running system isn't reliable - you can never know if system wouldn't crash in the middle leaving you with an unbootable and unaccessible, but not quite cleared system.

Comment: +1 Elegant!  I didn't know one could do that.

Comment: Perhaps you could even set DBAN as the default boot image. I'm not sure if it can be made to wipe a drive or set of drives without human intervention, but if it can (through boot command line parameters) then that may be a workable approach.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling: You can with `kernel=dban.bzi nuke="dwipe --autonuke"` but you'll have no confirmation of successful wipe and you'll have only one try &mdash; you wouldn't be able to boot back to system even if it was not properly wiped.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [`shred`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html) program from GNU coreutils.

One thing I've found to be useful, if you want to avoid "cutting the branch you're sitting on", is to create an initramfs image that includes `shred`, then burn that onto a bootable CD.

Comment: i will look into using this + find to exec shred on all important components of the servers.

Comment: I like that analogy: "*cutting the branch you're sitting on*"!

Answer (score 4):

If you're really worried about it, simply have them ship you the physical hard drives, then destroy them yourselves.

Comment: agreed. and take note of the serials numbers before and after to make sure its the same drives :)

Comment: @Sirex, and the SMART diagnostic power-on-time values!